# Adding standard Json Response for an API

Tags: c#, api, rest, asp.net-core, error-handling

How do I follow standard JSON API response format? My response is currently showing all the data which is a card being deleted. I'd like to output a success if a payment has been deleted successfully or a error if there was an error in deleting it.

Would I need to create a separate success and error model?

My controller

```cs
[HttpDelete]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult), 400)]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeletePaymentMethod(string paymentID)
{
    var userId = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "UserID").Value;
    var result = new VersionResponse()
        {
            Data = await _paymentService.DeletePaymentMethod(paymentID, userId)
        };
    return Ok(result);
}
```

my VersionResponse

```
public class VersionResponse
{
    public dynamic Data { get; set; }
}
```

Expected Response if successful:

```
{
  data : {
    success : true
  }
}
```

Expected Response if theres an error:

```
{
  error : {
    message : "Payment method does not exist", // string, user friendly message
    }
}
```

Current Response:

If there was only one payment Method there and it got deleted then this is the response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "data": []
    }
}
```

otherwise if we have multiple payment methods left then this is the response:

```
 "data": {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "pm_1HEllWCCQ3Wtmj18t8Dm08WD",
                "object": "payment_method",
                "billingDetails": {
                    "address": {
                        "city": null,
                        "country": null,
                        "line1": null,
                        "line2": null,
                        "postalCode": null,
                        "state": null,
                        "stripeResponse": null
                    },
                    "email": null,
                    "name": null,
                    "phone": null,
                    "stripeResponse": null
                },
                "card": {
                    "brand": "mastercard",
                    "checks": {
                        "addressLine1Check": null,
                        "addressPostalCodeCheck": null,
                        "cvcCheck": "pass",
                        "stripeResponse": null
                    },
                    "country": "US",
                    "expMonth": 8,
                    "expYear": 2022,
                    "fingerprint": "J2v2Z5D0AXU9RZRW",
                    "funding": "credit",
                    "last4": "4444",
                    "threeDSecureUsage": {
                        "supported": true,
                        "stripeResponse": null
                    },
                    "wallet": null,
                    "stripeResponse": null
                },
                "cardPresent": null,
                "created": "2020-08-11T00:54:59Z",
                "customerId": "cus_HT43dM2M6dWiDT",
                "customer": null,
                "fpx": null,
                "ideal": null,
                "livemode": false,
                "metadata": {},
                "sepaDebit": null,
                "type": "card",
                "stripeResponse": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What is being returned from `_paymentService.DeletePaymentMethod`?

Comment: I'm prefer create individual class for each. But can use master `interface` or `abstract class` should be work. However, in this case, need "$type" field to deserialize properly for Json.NET. It consumes additional bandwidth.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Updated my question to include what's being returned

Comment: Since you are assigning output of `_paymentService.DeletePaymentMethod` to Data property you are getting this response. You should create object of `VersionResponse` after calling `DeletePaymentMethod` method and assign value to data property. Or you can simply do `return Ok(new {data = new { success = true }});`

Comment: throw custom exception and handler exception global.in excepionhander,you can return data by exception type.

Comment: how would I only return the error message response?

Comment: [msdoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling)

Comment: @FLYFLU I'm currenltly getting this response as my error {
    "error": "Your card's expiration year is invalid."
}

Comment: How do I output it as this: {
  error : {
    message : "Payment method does not exist", // string, user friendly message
   
    }
}